# Calling a function in an external JavaScript from a sandboxed HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-app, sandbox

I'm helping to develop a Chrome application, where Google Blockly and its JS interpreter will be sandboxed. Here's what the root directory looks like:

[image]

Below is the directory of blockly folder:

[image]

I included blockly/index.html in manifest.json to sandbox it:

```
"sandbox": {
   "pages": ["blockly/index.html"]
}
```

I tried to call a function doSomething() in js/core/editorJavaScript.js in blockly/index.html like this:

```
<script src="../js/core/editorJavaScript.js"></script>
//other code
function example() {
  Espruino.Core.EditorJavaScript.doSomething(parameter);
}
```

However this doesn't seem to work - I keep getting an error from Chrome, which suggests editorJavaScript.js can't be seen by index.html even when it's included (I'm suspecting it's the double dots - are they allowed in sandbox?):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Espruino is not defined

So my question is, is it even possible to call a function in an external JS from a sandboxed HTML? If it is, what am I doing wrong? If it's not, is there an alternative to this problem? Any advice is appreciated and thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Inline JS is not allowed in Chrome app pages since Content Security Policy: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. But by sandboxing a html page, JS could be run within <script></script>? This is just my understanding - I could be wrong. Also my JS runs fine in the sandboxed page, except this line I mentioned in my post: Espruino.Core.EditorJavaScript.doSomething(parameter);